# How to fix this subset of errors

Tags: flutter, geocoding

Note: C:\Users\Gert\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\cloud_firestore-4.5.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\firestore\FlutterFirebaseFirestoreMessageCodec.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: C:\Users\Gert\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\geocoding_android-2.1.0\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\geocoding\Geocoding.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\Gert\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\geolocator_android-4.1.7\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\geolocator\location\FusedLocationClient.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\Gert\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\location-4.4.0\android\src\main\java\com\lyokone\location\FlutterLocation.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.

I have no clue in fixing any of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are deprecation warnings and are not errors. This warning shows that the third-party package that you use: in your case `firebase-firestore` and `geocoding` packages use deprecated apis in their code. These warnings are just for reference and should not cause any problems in building your application.

Deprecation warnings show that the third party package you are using in your flutter project use deprecated code and should be updated to latest apis. These are just for references and not a problem for you. These should be solved by the package authors. You could open a new issue in their package, but I doubt it will be solved.